# Bootstrap 4 CSS causing Chrome's print "Layout" to disappear

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout, printing, bootstrap-4

I want my website users to be able to print pages in either portrait or landscape mode.

When printing from Google Chrome using Bootstrap 3.3.7, the Chrome print settings has a Layout option.  Simply changing the css/js to 4.0.0, the Chrome print settings no longer has the Layout option.  I suspect this has something to do with one of these CSS directives:

```
@page
@media
```

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with Bootstrap 4 and Chrome and can confirm this resolves it. You should copy your fix into an answer and accept it.

Comment: There's a [bug report](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25629) for this.

Comment: This is still the case with Bootstrap 4.4 as can be demonstrated on their own page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 32):

I was able to fix this by adding this CSS:

```
@page {
    size: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Bootstrap 4.5 below code worked do not use ;

```
@media print { @page {size: auto !important} }
```

Answer (score 0):

in version 4.4 of Bootstrap, you need to set:

```
size: auto !important;
```