# Unable to change the margin & layout for printing in chrome browser from angular 2

Tags: angular, google-chrome, media-queries, printing-web-page

I'm trying to print HTML but I'm not able to change the **layout** and **margin** of the **chrome browser** (refer the attached image).

[image: This 1) Layout & 2) Margin remains the same]

```js
PRINT() {
  window.print();
}
```

```css
@media print {
  .doNotPrint {
    display: none;
  }
  * {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  @page {
    margin: 0 !important;
    size: A4 Landscape !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    size: A4 Landscape !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}
```

```html
<form [ngClass]="themeSRVC.currentThemeNAME" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
  <!-- navBAR -->
  <mat-toolbar id="idPrimaryTOOLBAR" color="primary" class="doNotPrint">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <button mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="routeSRVC.goBACK()">
        <mat-icon matTooltip="Go Back">arrow_back</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span class="fillSPACE"></span>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="PRINT()">
        <mat-icon matTooltip="print">print</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <!-- *****printableCONTENT***** -->
  <div id="idToPRINT" fxFlex>

    <div fxLayout="row">
      <div fxFlex="33" style="height:200px;background-color:red">Left</div>
      <div fxFlex style="height:200px;background-color:yellow">Center</div>
      <div fxFlex="33" style="height:200px;background-color:green"> Right</div>
    </div>


  </div>

</form>
```

Am I missing something..? please help me to remove the margin and change the layout.

Comment: Please stick to a naming convention in your CSS class/ID names: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)

Comment: u mean my naming conventions are causing this problem?? if so could you pls pin-point which name in my CSS is wrong.

Comment: I'm just saying that you _should_ stick to a naming convention. Not that your conventions cause the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours and hours of research... I finally figured it out.!

> set @media styles in the global **styles.scss** of your app.
>
> **NOT** in the **component.scss**

If you want to dynamically change the layout to portrait/landscape you can do like the following

> **1) Remove** the @media print{...} from the **global scss**
>
> **2)** and in your **component.ts** call the print function by passing true/false

```
PRINT(landscape: boolean) {
  var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.media = 'print';

  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(landscape ?
    '@page { size: A4 landscape; margin: 0in;}' :
    '@page { size: A4;  margin: 0in; }'));

  head.appendChild(style);
  window.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread may be old. However, if you programmer using CSS and you want to print but your layout option is not showing, kindly add this CSS line

"`@media print { @page {size: auto !important} }`" to your style sheet

[image]

I had similar issue but was able to solve using the above code. Source for the code is from this thread [Bootstrap 4 CSS causing Chrome's print "Layout" to disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018636/bootstrap-4-css-causing-chromes-print-layout-to-disappear) by @yeshwanthkv (@https://stackoverflow.com/users/3902260/yeshwanthkv)